# Best_in_place gem not saving? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, best-in-place

So, I'm using the [best in place gem](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) to allow users to edit their photos caption in place. However, the text that is entered isn't being saved or stored in the database.

**Here is a snapshot of the schema relevant to this area:**

```
create_table "photos", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "file"
    t.integer  "attachable_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "attachable_type"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.boolean  "profile_photo",   default: false
  end
```

**and here's the view code:**

```
<%= best_in_place photo, :description, type: :textarea, nil: 'Enter a Caption' %>
```

I can enter in the caption but when I refresh, it say's 'Enter a Caption' again and not the text that I've entered originally.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Rails 3 or Rails 4? You don't need both tags. Or the rubygems tag.

Comment: sevenseacat, we meet again. I am using Rails4, cheers!

Comment: Can you please paste your photo controllers update action, you need to provide respond_with_bip in else part.